# Windows XP on Intel 486?

Tags: windows-xp, intel-486

Windows XP on Intel 486, I have windows xp dvd and put it into Intel 486 computer, It not working, and tried put Windows XP Hard Drive into Intel 486 computer, It not working. Can Windows XP be booted on Intel 486?

Comment: this may be better asked on [retrocomputing.se]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Windows XP cannot run on a 486 processor.

The official listed minimum processor is:

> - Pentium or compatible, 233 MHz
> - BIOS or compatible firmware

Note, there were earlier processors that *could* run XP, but the 486 was still not one of them.

> Even though this is Microsoft's stated minimum processor speed for Windows XP, it is possible to install and run the operating system on early IA-32 processors such as a P5 Pentium without MMX instructions. Windows XP is not compatible with processors older than Pentium (such as 486) because it requires CMPXCHG8B instructions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#cite_note-ref1-88

Comment: The tricky thing I suspect is that the pentium non MMXes never went that fast. from memory, you'd be running a pentium pro or pentium II for that rated clock speed.

Answer (score 3):

No - Its *much* too old.

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP#System_requirements), you need at *least* a Pentium capable processor running at 233mhz (which practically would be something around a PII) and 128mb of ram.

486en lacked a good chunk of necessary instructions, probably topped out at maybe 64 mb of ram (though there's reports of suitable [128 mb](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=56970) chips working).

There's [reports](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26369) that windows 2000 will work but you're better off with a contemporary os like windowss 95 or 98, While in theory you *could* try to run linux on it, most common linuxes have apparently dropped support and you'd need some tuning to deal with the low specifications of the system. Someone did get [gentoo running in one](http://yeokhengmeng.com/2018/01/make-the-486-great-again/)